# How to clone a simple HTTPS repository in SmartGit?

Tags: git, ssh, smartgit

I want to clone a repository in SmartGit and have troubles with cloning. The current version of SmartGit says that I need some link in form `'ssh://user@server.port/repository-path or svn://server:post/repository-path'`.

I've heard that I need some SSH key, but I probably don't have it at all, as the repository which I have is just my public GitHub repository. It very likely doesn't have SSH or SVN keys, it has only HTTPS URL which doesn't seem to be acceptable in SmartGit.

When I copy-paste the URL to the 'Clone' window, it says

```
'Could not connect to the repository 'https://github.com/Clarity97'.

Please check the repository URL.

repository 'https://github.com/Clarity97/' not found'
```

So how to clone [my simple repository](https://github.com/Clarity97) to my SmartGit?

Comment: https://github.com/Clarity97 is not a repository, it's your profile at Github. https://github.com/Clarity97/SymfonyBlog and https://github.com/Clarity97/SonataAdminBundle are repositories. Well, even they are not repositories, they are web interfaces to repositories. https://github.com/Clarity97/SymfonyBlog.git and https://github.com/Clarity97/SonataAdminBundle.git are repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to any of your actual repositories (for instance https://github.com/Clarity97/SymfonyBlog), and you will see the "clone or download" button, which will give you the proper URL to use.

[image: clone or download]

Make sure to follow the [GitHub SSH guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) in order to generate and register a public SSH key to your GitHub profile.